# How to get the api returned data from a collection?

Tags: api, backbone.js, collections, model

I have the following collection that gets data from an api:

```
var Data = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: '/* api url - working */',

    sync: function(method, model, options) {
        options.timeout = 10000;
        options.dataType = "jsonp";
        return Backbone.sync(method, model, options);
    }
});
```

And I want to display it in the view:

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el : '.myview',
    render : function () {
        var data = new Data();
        var that = this;

        data.fetch({
            success : function (data) {
                console.log(arguments);
                console.log(data);

                var template = _.template( $('#temp').html(), {data: data.models} );
                that.$el.html(template);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

What I don't understand is that when I log `arguments` I get the api data and it has a wieired structure: `{0:child, 1:object\* contains the api data *\, 2:object}` but when I log `data` I get only the `child`

I don't understand this structure, what am I missing and how do I get the api data out of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Collection.fetch` is calling the success function you passed in with 3 arguments (from [Backbone source](http://backbonejs.org/backbone.js)):

```
success(collection, resp, options);
```

`arguments` is a special local variable in all javascript functions.  Check out this [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments).

So, logging `arguments` is showing the 3 things passed into the `success` function while logging `data` is showing just the first thing passed in. Even though your function only has 1 parameter, three things were still passed to it.

The first thing passed to `success` is the Backbone Collection itself.  So, what you need to do with it depends on what your template looks like.  It is common to pass just the JSON to the template function: `_.template( $('#temp').html(), {data: data.toJSON()} )`. Then in the template, you would need to iterate over those JSON objects.

```
 <% _.each(data, function(item){ %>
     <div><%= item.foo %></div>
 <% }); %>
```

Comment: My confusion is why the actual data I received from the api is the second argument, not the first? and what is an object called `child`? From your explanation it seems that I use the view and collection the right way

Comment: The second argument is whatever `ajax` passed to its `success` callback function (the one defined in Backbone.sync, not yours). Normally, you don't need to use that because the collection (first argument) has already been `reset` with that data. Maybe try `console.log(data.toJSON());` in your `success` function, that might help you understand it more. This should print out an array of JSON with each model's attributes.

Comment: In the first argument I don't get the ajax data, only in the second, is there something wrong with the collection that it doesn't have the ajax data?

Comment: What did `console.log(data.toJSON());` print? The first argument is not the ajax data, it is a [Backbone Collection](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection) instance with the ajax data parsed into [Backbone Models](http://backbonejs.org/#Model).